# Spring boot MBean metrics compatible with VisualVM graph output

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jmx, visualvm

I'm using SpringBoot to create a mirco-webservice, and want to use VisualVM to graph the essential performance stats for jetty that springBoot exposes. 
The data is very rich, but is in JSON format, which VisualVM does not seem able to generate graphs from.

If I use something like Dropwizard, the values are produced in a name/value pair format which VisualVm is happier with, and can use to generate graphs.

I really want to make use of the SpringBoot monitoring output because it provides such a rich set of metrics out-of-the-box.

Is there a way to either:

- get SpringBoot to output Jmx metrics as plain name/value pairs (suitable for graphing in VisualVM), or
- configure Visualvm to pick out specific JSON sub elements as source data for graphing ?

Comment: Have you tried using Spring Boot with Dropwizard's metrics on the classpath? The Boot metrics will be automatically published to the Dropwizard MetricsRegistry. That may be sufficient to get the necessary MBean(s) for VisualVM.

Comment: Could you please check hawtio helps you here : http://hawt.io/faq/